# Regex match pattern inside of existing match

Tags: regex

Not sure how to do this. Probably best illustrated with the following screen:

[image]

So I want the replaced text to read `yo yo` rather than `yo`.

That's both of the occurrences of `{{.*}}` rather than the large occurrence that wraps both of the search text.

Thanks.

Comment: Laziness (`.*?`) is a blessing in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've coded a *greedy* quantifier `.*`, which consumes as much as possible while still matching - ie it matches from the first `{{` to the last `}}`.

You want a *reluctant* quantifier:

```
{{.*?}}
```

which matches as *little* as possible, while still matching - ie it will match from the first `{{` to the *next* `}}`.

Comment: Perfect, I was going about that totally the wrong way. That worked, cheers. Accepted in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negated character class:

```
{{[^}]*}}
```